# How to (recursively) update a table based on available hierarchy?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Given these 3 column values, how can i update a table with the top level head for each employee?

```
| EmpID | EmpName | SupervisorID | DeptHeadID |
|:-----:|:-------:|:------------:|:----------:|
| 3     | Adam    |     null     |            |
| 1     | Sam     |     5        |            |
| 6     | Mike    |     2        |            |
| 5     | Jack    |     3        |            |
| 2     | Steph   |     5        |            |
| 8     | Rob     |     2        |            |
```

The result should be like this

```
| EmpID | EmpName | SupervisorID | DeptHeadID |
|:-----:|:-------:|:------------:|:----------:|
| 3     | Adam    |     null     |     null   |
| 1     | Sam     |     5        |     3      |
| 6     | Mike    |     2        |     3      |
| 5     | Jack    |     3        |     3      |
| 2     | Steph   |     3        |     3      |
| 8     | Rob     |     2        |     3      |
```

Comment: From the information provided it is not at all clear what you want to do here. Why does the SupervisorID for Steph change? And how could we know who the DepartmentHead id? Don't you have more than 1 department? You need to give us some details. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Not a very good example with only one dept head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

```
;with cteP as (
      Select EmpID,SupervisorID,TopLvl=EmpID
      From   YourTable 
      Where  SupervisorID is null
      Union  All
      Select r.EmpID,r.SupervisorID,TopLvl=p.TopLvl
      From   YourTable r
      Join   cteP p on r.SupervisorID  = p.EmpID)
Update YourTable
   set DeptHeadID = nullIf(TopLvl,A.EmpID)
 From  YourTable A
 Join  cteP B on A.EmpID=B.EmpID

-- Show Updated Table
Select * From YourTable
```

**Updated Table**

```
EmpID   EmpName SupervisorID    DeptHeadID
3       Adam    NULL            NULL
1       Sam     5               3
6       Mike    2               3
5       Jack    3               3
2       Steph   5               3
8       Rob     2               3
```

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: @akurudi Happy to help :)